# Set widget label next to input and minimize its distance over and under it

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to minimize the distance between a shiny widget and the box over and under it by setting its label next to it and the distances from boxes to 0 like:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(width=12),
      tags$head(
        tags$style(type="text/css", "label.control-label, .selectize-control.single{ display: inline-block!important; }")
      ),selectInput("select1", label = "Select vIEW", 
                    choices = list("Uptake first dose" , "Uptake full vaccination" ), 
                    selected = "Uptake first dose"),
      box(width = 12)
      ),
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```